# How to add copyright information to a Nib file?

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, nib, copyright-display

I've just finished a total re-write [1] of one of Apple's example applications and I am going to release my code as source only on GitHub, under a BSD license.

Adding the BSD license text to the .h and .m files is easy, and I can add copyright information to the .png assets that I will be including, but I am stumped as to how I can add the requisite license information to the xib files.  XCode regenerates the files after an edit, so anything manually added to an xml comment will be stripped off.

I'd like to add the license to the nib files for completeness but I am not hung up on doing it  - so can anyone offer any advice?

[1] The App was AccelerometerGraph and the re-write included displaying each accelerometer channel on a separate graph, providing additional signal inputs (sine, step and impulse) as well as additional filters (Butterworth 1st and 2nd order low high and bandpass).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that there is something you can do on `xib` level since even the IB inspector doesn't have any associated fields that you can edit for this. One solution though could be to add an `NSObject` in your `xib` (at root level), name it `Copyright` (or whatever) and add your information on the `Notes` field (identity inspector).

Now if don't want to add a new object in your `xib` just to hold this information, you could just add your copyright notice into the `File's Owner` notes field. Either way, the information will be included in the xml.

**I know** it's a bit of a hack but it's just an idea. If anyone though can think of a more proper way for achieving this I would be glad to know as well.

[image]

Comment: Thats something I hadn't thought about doing.  I have the feeling that any solution is going to be a bit of a hack - we'll just see who (if anyone) has the less hackish solution!

Comment: @PeterM Indeed... I'm very curious too!

Comment: I just tried this approach and discovered that when the the Notes text gets above some fixed size it is serialized to what looks like compressed and base 64 encoded bytes.  So while the full copyright notice can be seen in IB, it is effectively obsfucated in the xml file!  Thus I can only put an abbreviated copyright notice into the NIB and not the full BSD license text if I want it to be visible in the XML file.

Comment: Just did some more exploration .. it seems the encoding kicks in when carriage return chars are included into the Notes text.  So that makes it more usable.

Comment: More research shows that single or double quotes also trigger the encoding (Duh!), but back ticks are allowable.  So now I can get the full notice in human readable form in the xml file.

Comment: Oh man that's good stuff! Thanks for sharing Peter :) I'm sure that this question will be a reference for many people having the same need.

Comment: I'm going with your answer as that format is what I just uploaded to GitHub .. lol