# Sane localization workflow using Xcode 6, iOS 8, Storyboards and xliff?

Tags: ios8, localization, xcode6, uistoryboard, xliff

This is ideally what I'd like to do:

1. Set up a project in Xcode using a base localization of English. Ultimately I want English and let's say Dutch versions of my `Localizable.strings` and Storyboards
2. Externalise strings in code with `NSLocalizedString`, using keys of the form `fooViewController.barLabel`, being diligent and adding proper context comments with every key
3. Add a Dutch localization to my Storyboard files
4. Mark particular labels in the Storyboard as placeholders that will be set at runtime and do not require translations
5. Add comments for labels in the Storyboard which *do* require translation
6. Export the "development language" `xliff` file (Click on Project, Editor/Export For Localization..., choose "Development Language Only")
7. Open the English `xliff` file in a tool like [Counterparts](https://michelf.ca/software/counterparts-lite/) or [Xliffie](http://hotmilktea.com/xliffie/) or even something web based
8. Add actual English translations alongside the `fooViewController.barLabel` keys, and re-save the en.xliff
9. Create an `nl.xliff` file from the original `en.xliff` and add Dutch translations
10. Import both `xliff` files into Xcode and have it create the appropriate `.strings` files for both Dutch and English, for both the keys defined in code and those in the Storyboard; commit the new `.strings` files into my source repository
11. At some future point after keys have been added, removed and changed in my source and Storyboards, export the "Development language" `en.xliff` again as the source of truth
12. Update the `en.xliff` and `nl.xliff` files with current translations, having a tool highlight which keys had been added or removed
13. Import those `xliff` files back into Xcode which updates the `.strings` files I can then check back in to my source repository

Does this make sense? Is this a reasonable thing to want to do? I think so, but it doesn't work.

Here are the problems I ran into:

- Xcode does not support step 4—the `xliff` format can mark a key as `translate=no`, but there is no way to annotate that in Xcode (ideally, Xcode wouldn't export keys marked as placeholders at all.)
- Xcode does not support step 5—there is no way to set a translator comment for a label. There's not even a way to set the key independent of the placeholder text you put in the label on the Storyboard, which is a massive pain if you find filling labels with [Lorem Ipsum](http://baconipsum.com) useful when laying out your views.
- When you get to step 10, Xcode complains there is no target language specified in the `en.xliff` file. There is a way to change the target language (or, at least, create a new file with the target language set to `EN`) in Counterparts but I couldn't find any way to do this with Xliffie.
- Upon attempting to re-export the `en.xliff` file with updated keys, Xcode told me `"Localization failed reading "[...]/Supporting Files/en.lproj/Localizable.strings, Please address the issue at file location 782"` at which character location I found... an apostrophe. Xcode can't export an `xliff` file if the source `.strings` file contains an apostrophe. [What in the actual F...](http://replygif.net/558)?!
- Step 12 and 13 got weird, and I just don't understand what was happening. Both Counterparts and Xliffie had replaced my original `fooViewController.barLabel` keys with the English translations and looked like they were trying to tell me I had no English translations. Upon attempting to import the `en.xliff` back into Xcode it told me I had no translations for all but the new keys and when I went ahead, it wiped the existing translations from the `en.lproj/Localization.strings` file.

This is a mess.

Translating labels in Storyboards without being able to manually set their keys, add translator comments or mark particular labels as placeholders not-for-translation just doesn't work. We've resorted to connecting every label to an `@IBOutlet` and setting its translation in `viewDidLoad()` with `NSLocalizedString`.

Xcode choking when it attempts to export a `.strings` file containing an apostrophe beggars belief.

It also seems there's an underlying assumption that if the "development language" in Xcode is English, then the developers are in charge of the English translation. I can imagine no context outside that of a single-person indie developer shop where this is true.

Finally, it also seems I'm missing something about how the tools I've attempted to use structure their workflows. If anyone could enlighten me I'd be quite grateful.

Has anyone managed to construct a workable localization workflow where the developers aren't charged with ultimate editing control over the "development language" and the `.strings` files checked into the repository are the source of truth?

Comment: I submitted a Radar which was basically a pointer to this SO post and it got closed as a dupe: "Engineering has determined that your bug report (20134778) is a duplicate of another issue (20091629) and will be closed."

Answer (score 12):

> We've resorted to connecting every label to an @IBOutlet and setting its translation in viewDidLoad() with NSLocalizedString.

You are doing that right. Seriously. Wrap your development process around it and you'll get way better off than trying to adopt the mess that the Storyboard localization evolved into.

It solves pt.4 - you decide what you put in the `Localizable.strings`

It solves pt.5 - comments are there by default, for everything that you decide to be localizable. Now to be honest, XCode7 has added a possibility to [add notes to resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169641/what-is-the-purpose-of-notes-under-document-in-xcode). Don't use it. For some reason only known to Apple, it is not available for all types of resources. You can't annotate e.g. table headers and footers. More on that later.

I recommend making your own `NSBundle.localizedStringForKey` wrapper (macro) which provides the `value`. `NSLocalizedString` sets `value` to empty string, essentially forcing `key` to be used as the fallback translation content. Of all the already existing questionable macros, `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` takes the `value` but also all other 4 required parameters - not something you would like to use often.

Step 10 is caused by you trying to import a Base localization - the fact that it's english does not make any difference. If you want to "translate english" (i.e. professional correcture), you must add english as another standalone localization on top of Base. Technically it boils down to the Base xliff missing `<file target-language>` and `<target xml:lang>` properties. Due to some strange xliff mess similar to yours, i had to add those once manually. You don't want to do that :)

Re apostrophe glitch: iOS localization is an unreal garden of wonders, but i'm prety sure it's not THAT unreal :) Try opening the file in some hexcode displaying editor - what XCode renders may be quite different from what the file really contains.

> 7. ... even something web based

That's [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/) for us and it nicely shows everything wrong with Apple's idea of Storyboard localization. Translators need 3 things to do their work professionally: context, context and context. Apple seems to think that translators will gladly install the app, play with it and ask questions to get the context. Because, by default, **there is no human context in xliff export**. Now with Xcode7, you can add notes, but weirdly not everywhere. Even where you can, your note is appended at the end of already long `<note>` string with machine context - understandably needed for storyboard import matching, but useless and obstructive for the translator. Furthermore, in reality, the translator is a pro agency, or a language enthusiast. Even if you had a luck with properly equipped enthusiast, or you paid the agency premium for getting an extra customer care, you enter *The Hostile Desert Of Beta Distribution Options*. Apple's funny Testflight reincarnation will either need the translator to register as an Apple developer, or waiting for Apple's beta review - depending on how early in the app life you need the translation.

BTW i like your blog. Sometimes i feel like dumping my sourness and misfeature fatigue too, but never got as far as you :)

Comment: "If you want to "translate english" (i.e. professional correcture)." It's not just for correcture, it would allow you to use XLIFF as a way to automatically create and merge .strings files without messing with `genstrings` and other instruments. There is just no source language, only keys and comments. Weird that Xcode is so "smart" that it would not merge .strings file when target-language is your development language. Hope that I made some sense.

Comment: "you must add english as another standalone localization on top of Base" could you please elaborate? Have anyone tried that? If my development language is English (`developmentRegion` is `en`) Xcode won't let me add another localization for English language, only some region-specific English versions (`en-US`, etc).

Comment: @kean i wrote it wrong. Exporting Development language will give you en.xliff. Duplicating it to e.g. Base.xliff will allow you for having en.xliff translated (and reimported to Base loc) while keeping "clean" xliff copy for later merging. Translated xliff is unmergeable as it contains status markers, alt suggestions etc. `genstrings` is a toy, suitable at most for generating a one time initial basis. It is really much better to adopt the workflow from the beginning and write the strings manually as the development goes.