# Xcode Storyboard what is Document section for?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

What is the Document section when selecting the Identity inspector in any view.

Specially what are these squares with different colors for?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The whole Identity section of the identity inspector exists to make things more convenient for you in Xcode.

The Label field identifies the UI element in Xcode.Suppose you have three text fields in your window. Giving each text field a different label makes it easier to identify each text field.

Here is an example, create two UIViews in Storyboard, and use `Label` to identify each(**Clarify: You can't refer to UI element by its `label`, `Label` is just for convenience**):

[image]

The color label looks quite similar to color labels in operating system, but I haven't figure out how to use it in Xcode yet.

The note section give an attributed string with a key of userComments to the storyboard file. For the usage of note section, this post may help[how-to-add-copyright-information-to-a-nib-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207088/how-to-add-copyright-information-to-a-nib-file/11208398#11208398)

Comment: so setting label won't affect anything in the code. Right?